# How to set keyword argument if positioned parameter is passed instead

Tags: ruby

For backward compatibility reasons, is there a way to define the `my` method so the following two calls are identicals?

```
my(1, A)
my(1, before: A)
```

where `before` is a keyword argument.

I currently have

```
def my(n, klass)
 puts "#{n} and #{klass}"
end
```

Now I need to be able to call `my(1, before: A)` and get the same result (i.e. "1 and A")

The `my` method may be also called with a second keyword argument i.e. `my(1, before: A, after: B)`

```
def my(n, before, after: nil)
 puts "#{n} and #{before} but not #{after}"
end
```

Comment: `def my(n, maybe_afrer = nil, after: nil)` and check.

Comment: When I run `my(1, before: A)` I get `rake aborted!
unknown keyword: before`

Comment: Did you update the method definition?

Comment: Do you mean as suggested by Aleksei? Sure I did and I get  (not surprisedly to me)  the error above.

Comment: Can you post an update with a minimum working code of the old definition and the expected new behaviour?

Comment: Ah, more keyword arguments, I missed that. `def my(n, maybe_afrer = nil, **params)` then.

Comment: @iGian have a look and let me know if the question contains the info you asked for,

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for the update but the `klass` value is now within the `params` hash so the method doesn't behave like before.

Comment: Try: `def my(arg_1, arg_2 = nil, before: nil, **args);  arg_2 = before unless arg_2; end`

Comment: When I try your signature with `my(1, A)` I get `undefined local variable or method `after`

Comment: In your example here `def my(n, klass, after=nil)`, `after` is not a keyword argument, it is an argument with a default value. Anyway, you should review your question and post something closer (cleaned up) to the exact code you are testing or it's hard to help.

Comment: @iGian My bad I typed `=` instead of `:`. Fixed now. The method I'm trying now is the last one, called with the 3 different options `my(1, "A")`, `my(1, before: "A")`, and `my(1, before: "A", after: "B")` which in the first 2 cases should return `1 and A but not` and in the last one `1 and A but not B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your method as:

```
def my(n, klass = nil, before: nil)
  p n: n, klass: klass, before: before
end
```

This allows you to pass a positional argument or a keyword argument:

```
my(1, A)
#=> {:n=>1, :klass=>A, :before=>nil}

my(1, before: A)
#=> {:n=>1, :klass=>nil, :before=>A}
```

Within the method you could then assign one variable to the other, i.e. either:

```
def my(n, klass = nil, before: nil)
  klass ||= before
  p n: n, klass: klass
end

my(1, A)         #=> {:n=>1, :klass=>A}
my(1, before: A) #=> {:n=>1, :klass=>A}
```

or:

```
def my(n, klass = nil, before: nil)
  before ||= klass
  p n: n, before: before
end

my(1, A)         #=> {:n=>1, :before=>A}
my(1, before: A) #=> {:n=>1, :before=>A}
```

The latter might be cleaner along with an additional `after` keyword:

```
def my(n, klass = nil, before: nil, after: nil)
  before ||= klass
  p n: n, before: before, after: after
end

my(1, A, after: B)         #=> {:n=>1, :before=>A, :after=>B}
my(1, before: A, after: B) #=> {:n=>1, :before=>A, :after=>B}
```

---

Note that technically you can also pass both of `klass` and `before` or none at all:

```
def my(n, klass = nil, before: nil)
  p n: n, klass: klass, before: before
end

my(1, A, before: A) #=> {:n=>1, :klass=>A, :before=>A}
my(1)               #=> {:n=>1, :klass=>nil, :before=>nil}
```

You might want to raise an `ArgumentError` in those cases.

Answer (score 4):

Below is MCVE and the example of usage.

```rb
def my(after = nil, **args)
  after ||= args[:after]
  before = args[:before]
  puts "after = “#{after}” | before = “#{before}“"
end

my "A"
#⇒ after = “A” | before = ““
my after: "A"
#⇒ after = “A” | before = ““
my before: "B"
#⇒ after = “” | before = “B“
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. You are missing the first param. If I add it ```def my(n, after = nil, **args)
    after ||= args[:after]
    before = args[:before]

    puts "#{n} and #{after} but #{before}"
  end```

I get 

```
1 and A but
1 and  but A
1 and B but A
```   

the second case is wrong, before is saved as after.

Comment: This is MCVE and it works as expected. It’s now up to you to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unfortunately not very clear, but I *think* this should do what you want:

```rb
def my(n, klass=nil, before: klass, after: nil)
  local_variables.map {|var| next var.to_sym, binding.local_variable_get(var) }.to_h
end

my 1
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: nil, after: nil }

my 1, 'A'
#=> { n: 1, klass: 'A', before: 'A', after: nil }

my 1, before: 'A'
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: 'A', after: nil }

my 1, before: 'A', after: 'B'
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: 'A', after: 'B' }

my 1, 'A', after: 'B'
#=> { n: 1, klass: 'A', before: 'A', after: 'B' }

my 1, 'A', before: 'B', after: 'C'
#=> { n: 1, klass: 'A', before: 'B', after: 'C' }
```

If you want to know whether `klass` or `before` were passed, you have to use the old "assign a flag as a side-effect trick":

```rb
def my(n, klass=(klass_not_passed = true; nil), before: (before_not_passed = true; klass), after: nil)
  raise ArgumentError, "You may only pass one of `klass` or `before` but you passed `klass == #{klass.inspect}` and `before == #{before.inspect}`" unless klass_not_passed || before_not_passed

  local_variables.map {|var| next var.to_sym, binding.local_variable_get(var) }.to_h
end

my 1
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: nil, after: nil, klass_not_passed: true, before_not_passed: true }

my 1, 'A'
#=> { n: 1, klass: 'A', before: 'A', after: nil, klass_not_passed: nil, before_not_passed: true }

my 1, before: 'A'
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: 'A', after: nil, klass_not_passed: true, before_not_passed: nil }

my 1, before: 'A', after: 'B'
#=> { n: 1, klass: nil, before: 'A', after: 'B', klass_not_passed: true, before_not_passed: nil }

my 1, 'A', after: 'B'
#=> { n: 1, klass: 'A', before: 'A', after: 'B', klass_not_passed: nil, before_not_passed: true }

my 1, 'A', before: 'B', after: 'C'
# ArgumentError: You may only pass one of `klass` or `before` but you passed `klass == "A"` and `before == "B"`
# from test.rb:36:in `my'
```

Comment: Luckily even with very unclear requirements, the issue has been already solved (see the accepted answer). Thank you.